# C sizeof char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, size

Hello i'm beginner in C programming. I'm making program that should crawls though elements of a string, the string is input from the user. 
The problem is that I need the size of the characters in the string I have try a lot of thing none of them worked.

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= cUserInput; i++){
        if(&cUserInput[i] == cFirstLineR[i]){
        printf("Check///Failed\n");
    }
```

`cUserInput` is the user input. I need its size.

`cFirstLineR` is an array of characters to camper with.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To know what you are after, you'd have to give use a bit more information. Give use the declaration of all variables involved. You may use the "edit" functionality to amend your question.

Comment: How do you get the user input? Is it a NUL terminated string?

Comment: Here is a part from my source code:

    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char cFirstLineR[] = {'u','i','o','p','U','I','O','P','j','k','l','J','K','L','n','m','N','M'};
    char cUserInput[100];
    fgets(&cUserInput, 100, stdin);
    for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(cUserInput) - 1; i++){
       if(&cUserInput[i] == &cFirstLineR[i]){
        printf("Check///Failed\n");
        }
     return 0;
}

Now the if loop seens to work correct but, I have problem with te if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `strlen(const char* str)` to get a strings' size. It will count the characters until the `NUL` terminator. See reference here:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

NOTE: to use it you have to include the header `"string.h"`

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `sizeof ()` that should work with your problem...

Comment: This may or may not work, depending on whether `cUserInput` is declared as an array or a pointer.